# Format IEnumerable Using LINQ (VB.NET)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to fix my data to be able to display properly.

I

**Expected output**

```
Manager: Jane Lynch | Start Date: 01-01-2015 | End Date: 01-01-2020
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Employee: James Pierce
| Employee: Jesse Mats
| Employee: Anna Boxes
Manager: Rob Riggle | Start Date: 05-10-2016 | End Date: 04-01-2022
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Employee: Paul Rudd
| Employee: Mike Judge
```

**Current data output**

```
Manager: Jane Lynch | Start Date:  | End Date: 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Employee: James Pierce
| Employee: Jesse Mats
| Employee: Anna Boxes
Manager: Rob Riggle | Start Date:  | End Date: 
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Employee: Paul Rudd
| Employee: Mike Judge
```

**Code Structure**

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Data.DataSetExtensions
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq

Public Module Module1

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim employees As List(Of Employee) = New List(Of Employee)()
    employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = "1", .FullName = "Jane Lynch", .StartDate = New DateTime(2015, 1, 1), .EndDate = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1), .Manager = ""})
    employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = "2", .FullName = "James Pierce", .StartDate = New DateTime(2015, 1, 1), .EndDate = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1), .Manager = "Jane Lynch"})
    employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = "3", .FullName = "Jesse Mats", .StartDate = New DateTime(2015, 1, 1), .EndDate = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1), .Manager = "Jane Lynch"})
    employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = "4", .FullName = "Anna Boxes", .StartDate = New DateTime(2015, 1, 1), .EndDate = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1), .Manager = "Jane Lynch"})
    employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = "5", .FullName = "Rob Riggle", .StartDate = New DateTime(2016, 5, 10), .EndDate = New DateTime(2022, 4, 1), .Manager = ""})
    employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = "6", .FullName = "Paul Rudd", .StartDate = New DateTime(2015, 1, 1), .EndDate = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1), .Manager = "Rob Riggle"})
    employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = "7", .FullName = "Mike Judge", .StartDate = New DateTime(2015, 1, 1), .EndDate = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1), .Manager = "Rob Riggle"})
    Dim groupedEmployees As List(Of EmpGroup) =(From emp As Employee In employees Group By manager = emp.Manager Into g = Group Select New EmpGroup With {.Manager = manager, .employees = g}).ToList


    For Each emp In groupedEmployees
        If emp.Manager <> "" Then
            Console.WriteLine(emp.Manager)
            Console.WriteLine("----------")
            For Each s In emp.Employees
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}", s.FullName)
            Next
        End If
    Next

    End Sub

    Class Employee

        Property ID As Integer = 0
        Property FullName As String = String.Empty
        Property StartDate As Date = Nothing
        Property EndDate As Date = Nothing
        Property Manager As String = String.Empty
    End Class
    Class EmpGroup
        Property Manager As String
        Property Employees As IEnumerable(Of Employee)
    End Class

End Module
```

This is where Im currently at. I thought by grouping them I could make this a bit easier.

Also, The rows have to be grouped because I will be adding them to a `ul` which is the reason why I used an `|` to help convey that is the intended output.

Thanks in advance for all comments and suggestions.

Comment: You know that the code in your question doesn't compile (at least with `Option Strict On`)?

Comment: Not really a big issue since I'm aware that there is an implicit conversion of the ID property from a String to an Int

Comment: I'd suggest that you code with `Option Strict On` - it'll squash a bazillion bugs before they get you at run-time.

Comment: Yes thank you. This was just a contrived example. I have Option Strict On set as a default for all my production code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim employees As List(Of Employee) = New List(Of Employee)()
employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = 1, .FullName = "Jane Lynch", .StartDate = New DateTime(2015, 1, 1), .EndDate = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1), .Manager = ""})
employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = 2, .FullName = "James Pierce", .StartDate = New DateTime(2015, 1, 1), .EndDate = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1), .Manager = "Jane Lynch"})
employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = 3, .FullName = "Jesse Mats", .StartDate = New DateTime(2015, 1, 1), .EndDate = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1), .Manager = "Jane Lynch"})
employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = 4, .FullName = "Anna Boxes", .StartDate = New DateTime(2015, 1, 1), .EndDate = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1), .Manager = "Jane Lynch"})
employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = 5, .FullName = "Rob Riggle", .StartDate = New DateTime(2016, 5, 10), .EndDate = New DateTime(2022, 4, 1), .Manager = ""})
employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = 6, .FullName = "Paul Rudd", .StartDate = New DateTime(2015, 1, 1), .EndDate = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1), .Manager = "Rob Riggle"})
employees.Add(New Employee With {.ID = 7, .FullName = "Mike Judge", .StartDate = New DateTime(2015, 1, 1), .EndDate = New DateTime(2020, 1, 1), .Manager = "Rob Riggle"})

Dim lookup = employees.ToLookup(Function (e) e.Manager)

For Each manager In lookup("")
    Dim line = String.Format("Manager: {0} | Start Date : {1:MM/dd/yyyy} | End Date : {2:MM/dd/yyyy}", manager.FullName, manager.StartDate, manager.EndDate)
    Console.WriteLine(line)
    Console.WriteLine("".PadRight(line.Length, "-"c))
    For Each employee In lookup(manager.FullName)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("| Employee: {0}", employee.FullName))
    Next
Next
```

I get:

```
Manager: Jane Lynch | Start Date : 01/01/2015 | End Date : 01/01/2020
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Employee: James Pierce
| Employee: Jesse Mats
| Employee: Anna Boxes
Manager: Rob Riggle | Start Date : 05/10/2016 | End Date : 04/01/2022
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| Employee: Paul Rudd
| Employee: Mike Judge
```